# Resource management in cache manifest

Tags: html, audio, offline-mode, cache-manifest

Im working on an offline html5 audio player. Obviously I have to specify filetypes such as Mp3 for use with webkit and Vorbis for firefox etc as per the HTML5 spec. However for use on mobile devices like the iPhone for example I only want to get the files needed to play in this case mp3. Is there a way for me to tell browsers to cache specific files or do they have to add all the resources no matter what. Thus eliminating the burden of the user having to cache more files needed and exceeding restrictions (I'm aware that in mobile safari only 10MB can be cached.)

Is there a way to target certain resources in the cache per device.

Heres my manifest.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:

index.html
master.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
style.css
buttons.png
image.jpg
/player/tunes/waterfall-audio.m4a
/player/tunes/waterfall-audio.oga
```

So obviously in firefox I only need to cache the oga and webkit the mp3. Any insights would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way in which you can target specific devices or platforms in cache manifest file.

But you can generate the manifest file on server side depending on the client that has sent the request. This way you can send different manifest files for different browsers and platforms.

Just make sure to set the MIME type to "text/cache-manifest".

Comment: Okay that sounds good how would this be achieved server side?

Comment: I am not much familiar with server side coding, but you can make the manifest file dynamic, like a dynamic web page. you can make the server to process the script code in manifest file and then use the request headers to determine the browser.